# Execute Cucumber Step Defination with multiple files with Page Object Model

Tags: selenium, pageobjects, cucumber-java

I am trying to execute a Cucumber Feature file which Step Definition in two different files. All methods in first Step Defination is executed and when executing second one, It launches a new browser instance, instead of continuing with existing one.

Cucumber Feature file
  Scenario: Given I open Firefox and Navigate to Guru
    When I enter UserName and Password and login to guru
    And I click on New Customer
    Then New Customer Page is displayed
    And I click on HomePage
    Then HomePage is displayed

**First Step Definition**

```
package stepDefination;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import Pages.HomePage;
import Pages.NewCustomerPage;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class GuruStepDef {
    WebDriver Driver;
    NewCustomerPage customerPage;
    HomePage homePage = new HomePage(Driver);

    @When("^I enter UserName and Password and login to guru$")
        public void I_enter_and_and_login_to_guru()  {
            homePage=homePage.setup();
            homePage.navigateToWebApp();
        }

@Then("^HomePage is displayed$")
    public void Homepage_is_displayed()  {
        //assert
    }

@Then("^I click on New Customer$")
    public void I_click_on_New_Customer() {
       customerPage= homePage.NavigateToCustomerPage();
    }

@Then("^New Customer Page is displayed$")
    public void New_Customer_Page_is_displayed()  {
      //assert
    }
```

}

**Second Step Definition**

```
package stepDefination;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import Pages.HomePage;
import Pages.NewCustomerPage;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;

public class SmokeTest {

    WebDriver Driver;
    NewCustomerPage customerPage;
    HomePage homePage = new HomePage(Driver);

@Then("^I click on HomePage$")
    public void I_click_on_HomePage()  {
        homePage=customerPage.Manager();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In both classes, you have:

```
HomePage homePage = new HomePage(Driver);
```

You are creating two instances of HomePage.  If you want to utilize the same object, you'll need to share it between the two classes.  For example, you could create HomePage in one of the classes and use a getter in the other, or you could use a Singleton pattern in the object itself to ensure only one instance is created at a time.